# Slack Webhooks with Angular $http POST

Tags: angularjs, post, webhooks, slack

I am trying to learn some basic Slack API stuff and am starting with building a webhook for an app I am building.

I have the following code:

```
$scope.postToSlack = function(){
    $http({
        url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx',
        method: "POST",
        payload:{"text": "This is a line of text in a channel.\nAnd this is another line of text."}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```

But keep getting a 500 error saying No Payload Received.

Any ideas on why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try data instead of payload (assuming you have your whole Access-Control-Allow-Origin stuff setup at the server).

```
$scope.postToSlack = function(){
    $http({
        url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx',
        method: "POST",
        data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({"text": "blah"})
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```

FYI - you probably want to do this on the server-side.  Just a suggestion:

1. You don't have to worry about the whole cross-domain posting craziness
2. You won't be sharing the url for your slack webhook with the world.

Maybe its not open or you are just playing around, but just thought I'd mention it early.

Comment: Add    `headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }` to make it work client side

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me -

```
$http({
    url: slackWebHookUrl,
    method: "POST",
    data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({"text": message,"channel" : slackChannelname, "username" : slackUsername}),
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log("Slack response :" + JSON.stringify(response));
}, 
function(error) {
    console.log("Slack error :" + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```